# How to check WITH statement is empty or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Have CTE like :

```
WITH fnl as
    (select lo.id , s.service_name , lo.obj_name ,
    ........
    from dbo.r_objects ro
    inner join dbo.services  s on ro.service_id = s.id 
    inner join dbo.local_objects lo on ro.local_object_id = lo.id
    where ro.service_id = @service_id
)
    select id , service_name , CAST(obj_name as varbinary(200)) obj_name
    FROM fnl 
    WHERE ....... some logic
```

Its work good . Now i want check if data in **fnl** is empty then write **'Data is empty'**
I try like :

```
WITH fnl as
    (select lo.id , s.service_name , lo.obj_name ,
    ........
    from dbo.r_objects ro
    inner join dbo.services  s on ro.service_id = s.id 
    inner join dbo.local_objects lo on ro.local_object_id = lo.id
    where ro.service_id = @service_id
)
    select @table_count = COUNT(*) from fnl 
IF @table_count > 0
begin
    select id , service_name , CAST(obj_name as varbinary(200)) obj_name
    FROM fnl 
    WHERE ....... some logic
    end

else
  set @check = 'Data is empty'
  ...............some logic here
```

when i exec procedure have an error : **Invalid object name 'fnl'**  How to check it on empty ? I try `IF EXISTS` but have an error too

**EDIT :**
**I solve it , create #tbl and then insert all data which is in fnl to #tbl because in CTE fnl you can use only once , I use it twice and have an error. then check if exists any data like this :** `IF EXISTS (select top 1 1 from #tbl)` *if there exists data then select data from #tbl else use some logic*

Comment: @usr I updated post , in else statement will be some logic if fnl will be empty

Comment: As Anon's answer shows below, you probably don't need the CTE.  (There is no join to `fnl`, so it's not really recursion, right?)  But since your check is **right after** you loaded #tbl, there is an option even faster, than the `IF EXISTS` you and Anon are using:  `IF @@rowcount > 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select lo.id , s.service_name , lo.obj_name ,
    ........
    INTO #temp
    from dbo.r_objects ro
    inner join dbo.services  s on ro.service_id = s.id 
    inner join dbo.local_objects lo on ro.local_object_id = lo.id
    where ro.service_id = @service_id

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp)
begin
    select id , service_name , CAST(obj_name as varbinary(200)) obj_name
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE ....... some logic
    end
else
begin
  set @check = 'Data is empty'
  ...............some logic here
  end
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a temp table vs just using the query directly in the IF EXISTS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CTE is appropriate use for the query that you have. I would be much better to do something like this. Instead of your CTE just place what you have inside that sub select. Later you can continue checking your vairable.

```
DECLARE @table_count INT
SELECT @table_count = COUNT(*)
   FROM ( SELECT somestuff
      FROM SOMEtables ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions only exist for the next SQL Statement.  Consider adjusting your approach - Why are you checking if the data is empty at this stage?  That sort of checking is better handled on the application side.

Alternatively, if you definitely want to do this in the database, here are alternatives you can do:

- Use an Inline Table Valued Function
- Use a table parameter to store the data
- Use a cut down version of the SQL Statement to check.  Additionally, using EXISTS is better than doing a count, for determining if there is any data.